# React: Update data variable of element by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getelementbyid

Because of performance issues, for the faster running, I would like to refresh the cells of a grid one by one. I have successfully been able to change the design of these cells in the following way:

```
document.getElementById(`cell-${cell.row}-${cell.col}`).className =
      "cell cell-isPlaced";
```

Each cell has a data variable `props.data.num` that I would like to refresh the same way, as I change its design. For some reason, the following code does not refresh the number on the grid (For easier understanding, each cell has the value of 0, that I want to change to 1):

```
document.getElementById(`cell-${cell.row}-${cell.col}`).num = 1;
```

Cell:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
  let cell = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`cell ${getColor(props)}`}
        id={`cell-${props.data.row}-${props.data.col}`}
      >
        {props.data.num}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return cell();
};

export default Cell;
```

Can the data of an element be changed in such a way as I am trying to do? (In general, all cell's display the 0 num, there's no problem with that).

Render of grid:

```
let grid = this.state.grid.map((row, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index} className="row">
          {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
            return (
              <Cell
                key={cellIndex}
                data={cell}
              />
            );
           })}
       </div>
      );
    });
```

Data in a cell during initialization:

```
 function createGrid(props) {
  let grid = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < props.rows; i++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < props.columns; j++) {
      grid[i].push({
        row: i,
        col: j,
        num: 0,
      });
    }
  }
  return grid;
}
```

Comment: What is the value props.data holds, can you give a sample.

Comment: @vikashvik Absolutely, I have updated the question, now hopefully with every info that is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically your component does not refresh because *React* does not know that it should rerender:

> React schedules a render every time the state of a component changes.

and

> As a result of that, the child components only updates when the state of the parent component has been changed with one of those functions.

As you don't change the state of the component via a `setState` function or it's functional equivalent, no re-renders are triggered. You can read more about this topic [here](https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/#what-is-rendering).

In order to fix this, I guess you have two options. Either convert the update of the num props to a setState function or try the brute force way and do a `this.forceUpdate()` for class components, or something like this for functional components:

```
const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0);
const refresh = () => setUpdate(update + 1);
```